# UIView shows the subview view sometimes?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiview

I am developing iOS game and need custom animation so I am using this method

```
    CGRect basketTopFrame = mainScreenView.frame;
basketTopFrame.origin.x = 320;
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
mainScreenView.frame = basketTopFrame;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

in the .h file I have declared mainScreen like this

```
IBOutlet UIView *mainScreenView;
```

So in the IB I have put UIView in the view in the interface and hooked it up with mainScreenView

So in the mainViewScreen the view sometimes shows up sometimes doesn't (works on the 2nd try) however when I remove the animation code it works perfectly fine..I don't know what is happening any help would be appreciated thanks

edit
this is how I added the view

```
MainScreen *mainScreen = [[MainScreen alloc]initWithNibName:@"MainScreen" bundle:nil];
[mainScreenView addSubview:mainScreen.view];
```

Comment: I am a little confused, you say sometimes the view shows up. But if you set the x to 320, at least on an iPhone in portrait mode, your moving your view out of the view. So what is your animation supposed to do? And when are you calling the animation?

Comment: That is when the animation method is called intitally the view is on (0,0)

Comment: here is an image what [happens](http://imgur.com/ZwbSC)

Comment: So when I am correct, when you click the button, you animate the view in (or out, I am still not sure ;)) For instance when you would animate the view in, I would set the x to -320 just before the animation, and within the animation set the x to 0. In short I would set the frame before the animation as well.

Comment: I am not quite sure what you mean there...but see the answer below and the same thing happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried it in a sandbox project, and this worked for me:

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouched:(id)sender {
    myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(-320, 0);

    [UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
    [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
    [UIView setAnimationDelay:.5];
    [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
    myView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(0,0);
    [UIView commitAnimations];

}
```

Comment: Alright the animation is working correctly however the view doesn't show up as the subview of myView in this case if that makes any sense

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. myView in the example was just a subview of the viewControllers main view, I added in the interface builder.

Comment: Alright here it goes once again....the image I posted [here](http://imgur.com/ZwbSC) is from two diffrent builds (note that I haven't clicked on the button thus NOT called the animation method)...in one build the view loads up normally in the second build however it doesn't (I just get the gray screen); I have updated the code a bit so have a look thanks

Comment: O, I see, mainScreen is a controller and you add its view as an subView to the mainScreenView. But what happens to the mainScreen object after you added its view, I think you need to keep a reference to it, otherwise it will be released.

Comment: I don't release (and have it declared it in the .h file) and I initialize the variables in viewDidLoad method..

Comment: MainScreen *mainScreen = ... is not referenced in your .h, since you defining a new one here. If you are not using ARC and you are not releasing it, you have at least a memory leak. Nevertheless, this object is just 'hanging' around and I can not predict what is happening to its view

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are trying to move something off screen. An easier way is to do this

```
[UIView beginAnimations:@"UIBase Hide" context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5];
[UIView setAnimationDelay:.5];
[UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseIn];
mainScreenView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(320,0); //slide view to the right. 
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

note: using 320 on the Translation wont move the view to the 320th pixel of the screen rather it moves your view 320px to the right. So if your mainScreenView is at origin.x = 100. After this translation it is now at 420.

To move it back do

```
 self.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
```